# SPServices how to query or check if an event exists within a specific time

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices

I have multiple calendars assigned to a conference room and goes to an approval process.

I want to create an application where I can select dynamically a calendar and add event to it through a form.

my problem is don't know how to check if an event overlaps with the current event I am creating.

I am using SPServices